# output the 2nd column of a file

Tags: linux

given a file with two columns, separatedly by standard white space

```
a b
c d
f g
  h
```

how do I output the second column

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the last line of your example data has no first column you'll have to parse it as fixed width columns:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = "2 1"} {print $2}'
```

Comment: @"James C" what does the fieldswidth = "2 1" mean?

Comment: that the first column is two characters wide and that the second column is one character wide

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for the naive example and does not address the general question at all. Roman's answer is accurate and acceptable.

Answer (score 56):

1. `cut -d' ' -f2`
2. `awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: the `-d` stands for "delimiter", to help remember

Comment: Neither of these work with the example data. The final row has only the second column.

Comment: it prints out a number of blank lines, I had to try cut -d' ' -f1 c | awk '{print $1}' but it combined both columns from the source file c..

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that there're blank fields. USe the James' solution, I believe it'll solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use cut with byte offsets:

```
cut -b 3
```

Use sed to remove trailing columns:

```
sed s/..//
```

Comment: That only works for the naive example; it does not even begin to address the general question.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
cut -c2 listdir
```

Here you can see for visualization:

[image]